# Linear Regression with moderator variables

Tags: regression, interaction

I am trying to create a linear regression with moderator variables. The data set looks as following:

```
Seq.    StimuliA    StimuliB    R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  ModeratorA  ModeratorB 
1           1           0        1  0   0   0   1   6       1           1
2           0           0        5  0   1   0   0   0       0           1   
2           0           1        3  0   0   1   0   0       2           0   
4           1           0        1  0   4   0   0   1       0           0
```

StimuliA and StimuliB are the independent variables and R2-R7 are the dependent/response variables. The Sequences (Seq.) are for a certain user who experienced a Stimuli A, B or no Stimuli at all. A user could have more than one sequence. The users then showed different responses R2-R7. The ModeratorsA and B simply show if this users in his history already has experienced one of the two Stimulis before and how many times.

Questions:
- Is this the right use of the moderator variables? If not, how would i structure the equation?
f.e `R2 = StimuliA + StimuliB + ModeratorA + ModeratorB` and this for all the different dependent variables?

I am using R, let me know whether you would like to have a reproducible example. For now, I am just curious whether or not my equation is correct. Any further tipps are absolutly welcome.

Comment: could please you edit to fix the spelling of "dependent"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like the responses are counts, which would mean you should use a count regression model such as Poisson or negative binomial.

Second, I think it might be better to use "seq" as the independent variable, just be sure to make it categorical.  This automatically gets at the interaction between A and B (if there is one).  But, you may have reason to use just A and B.

Third, to get to your question, no, that's not moderation.  To have moderation, you need to look at the interactions between the independent variables and the moderators.  Look for the `formula` help page in R to see how to do this.